# Bar highchart just shows one value of my array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using `highchart` to draw a bar chart in mvc .as you can see here is my code:

```
   Highcharts chartArticleCount = new Highcharts("chart1")
                  .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = majors })
                  .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "تعداد مقالات" } })
                  .SetSeries(new Series { Data = new Data(new object[] {majorArticleCount.ToArray()}), Name = "محور های همایش" })
                  .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "" })
                  .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column });
```

as you can see in the picture my data contains two values :

[image]

and

[image]

But the chart just shows one of them the last value .why?
[image]

When i change my code to this it works why?

```
 Highcharts chartArticleCount = new Highcharts("chart1")
                  .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new string[]{"salam","khobi"} })
                  .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "تعداد مقالات" } })
                  .SetSeries(new Series { Data = new Data(new object[] {"1","2"}), Name = "محور های همایش" })
                  .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "" })
                  .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column });
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to illustrate the issue more clearly?

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi i added some details to the post

Comment: your data must have an array,simply calculate at backend provide an array to data attribute of charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
majorArticleCount.ToArray()
```

This is the list of integer and should be converted to object :

```
object[] pointnum = new object[majorArticleCount.Count];
            pointnum = majorArticleCount.Cast<object>().ToArray();
            Highcharts chartArticleCount = new Highcharts("chart1")
                      .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = majors })
                      .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "تعداد مقالات" } })
                      .SetSeries(new Series { Data = new Data(pointnum.ToArray()), Name = "محور های همایش" })
                      .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "" })
                      .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column });
```

As you can see i create an object array and cast my list to that and pass the object array to my chart.

Comment: Is this answer to the question? I mean, you answer your own question with `Hope this works for you` ;) You hope that your answer will work for ... you?